# How to enable rules provided by StyleCop in Quality Profile - Sonar 5.1

Tags: sonarqube5.1

I am trying to follow the [link](http://docs.sonarqube.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=1441942) to enable StyleCop analysis for my .NET project. I am unable to set-up StyleCop rules in Quality Profile. I am using Sonar 5.1.

Basically I would like to incorporate StyleCop rules for the analysis rather than the default SONARWAY rules.

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by leveraging the [Set-up StyleCop Rules for SONAR](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2015/09/29/quickstart-analyzing-net-projects-with-sonarqube-msbuild-or-visual-studio-online-and-third-party-analyzers-stylecop-resharper.aspx#_Adding_the_StyleCop) link. This provides a detail overview as to how the same can be achieved

To summarize, all we need to do is:

1. Choose Quality Profiles and select the default Sonar Way profile.
2. Choose Copy, and create a new quality profile named STYLECOP Profile.
3. Choose Set as Default in the “STYLECOP” entry to set it as the default for C# projects
4. Choose Rules in the top navigation toolbar and then set the Repository textbox in the left-hand column
5. Select StyleCop in the Repository list to see the list of rules
6. Select all the StyleCop rules (when using a mouse you can click on the first rule, scroll to the end, and Shift-click the last one)
7. Choose Bulk Change and then choose Activate In. From the drop-down list, choose the STYLECOP profile
8. After a few seconds, SonarQube tells you that rules were added to the STYLECOP quality profile

Re-running the analysis

Just as before, I run the commands (to set the PATH variable):

1. path=%path%;C:\Sq\MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner-1.0.1
2. MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe begin /k:"StyleCopTest" /n:"StyleCopTest" /v:"1.0" /d:sonar.resharper.solutionFile="D:\TestStyleCop.sln"
3. msbuild "D:\TestStyleCop.sln"
4. MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe end